# Tab completion, rlcompleter in Emacs

Tags: emacs, tab-completion

I have a Python program which uses rlcompleter to provide custom Tab-completion. The completion works when it is run under a bash terminal. However, it does not work under emacs, in `shell` mode, nor in `eshell` mode.

I noticed that `Tab` is really bound to `completion-at-point`, `eshell-pcomplete`, and so on, so I tried an `(insert "\t")`, supposing that this would trigger the completion, which I understand happens when the child process reads a "\t" character. But this does not work either. Perhaps input is buffered until a "RET"?

Completion for commands like `service`, which define their own candidates, does not work as expected either.

How can I access these candidates within Emacs?

Comment: Have you tried `M-x ansi-term`?

Comment: Ah, such a simple answer. Can you please add it so I can accept it?

Comment: Glad it helped. There is no shortage of terminal options within emacs, it gets a bit difficult to know which does what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `M-x ansi-term`. I find it behaves a bit more like what I have come to expect from a *nix terminal.